# How to get event When callee rejects the call

Tags: twilio, voip

I am creating conference for outbound call. so how can we determine(know) when the callee rejects the calls. as i can't end the conference without knowing that the callee has rejected call or not. we do get 'participant-join' event if callee accepts the call or 'participant-leave' when participant leaves the conference but we do not get event when callee rejects the call. so because of that i am unable to end conference.

EDIT :

```
client.conferences(event.TaskSid)
        .participants
        .create({
            from: 'client:from',
            to: workerAttributes.contact_uri,
            earlyMedia: true,
            startConferenceOnEnter: true,
            statusCallback: 'https://' + context.domain_name + '/call-events?' + querystring.stringify(statusCallbackArgs),
            statusCallbackEvent: ["initiated", "ringing", "answered", "completed"],
            conferenceStatusCallback: 'https://' + context.domain_name + '/conf-events' + confEventArgs,
            conferenceStatusCallbackEvent: ["join", "leave", "end"],
            conferenceRecord: 'true',
            conferenceRecordingStatusCallback: 'https://' + context.domain_name + '/recording?ConferenceName=' + event.TaskSid,
            conferenceRecordingStatusCallbackEvent: ['completed'],
            waitUrl: 'https://' + context.domain_name + '/wait' + waitArgs,
            timeout: taskAttributes.timeout || 15
        });
```

So above is how i create conference. where i am passing statusCallbackArgs , confEventArgs , waitArgs as needed per requirements.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you making the outbound call? Can you share your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @philnash I have just updated the question. is this okay? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You have provided a `statusCallback` URL, a `conferenceStatusCallback` URL, and a `conferenceRecordingStatusCallback` URL and the callbacks that are going to help here are the requests to your `statusCallback` URL.

When a request is made to the `statusCallback` URL it includes a [`CallStatus` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters). That [`CallStatus` can be](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#callstatus-values) queued, ringing, in-progress, completed, busy, failed, no-answer or canceled.

The statuses that mean the callee rejected the call are busy or no-answer and that's what you should look for in order to end the conference.

Comment: I also create conference when we get incoming call and at that time i am getting 'no-answer' , 'cancelled' and 'busy' status when call is rejected but when creating outgoing call i am not getting above statuses when callee rejects the call.. not sure why that is

Comment: So are you saying you are not receiving webhooks to your `statusCallback` URL?

Comment: yes.. receiving webhook for incoming calls for 'no-answer' , 'cancelled' and 'busy'  but not for outgoing call

Comment: An incoming call cannot be no-answer, cancelled or busy because the call is incoming. I just ran a quick test and I was able to get "initiated", "ringing", "in-progress" and "completed" callbacks for an outbound call I made using the participants resource. I was able to get a "completed" event with the call status "no-answer" by setting the timeout to 5 seconds so that my voicemail did not start. Is it possible that when your caller rejects the call they are actually sending you to voicemail?